# Cursor isn't moving to first?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, android-studio

so I've build a method that return an ArrayList of a class that I use on my project, the problem is that the only item that is being add to the ArrayList is the 2nd on the database. I know that because I extracted the DB File and browsed it, and also the 'c.getCount()' return a value of 2.

So I know for a fact that my DB includes 2 entries, my Cursor gets 2 entries... but for some reason he chooses to focus on the 2nd row at the beginning after I created it - and thus exiting the while loop, even thought I called c.moveToFirst();

Maybe I'm just tired and not seeng clearly what am I doing wrong... because I compared it to other methods in my code that works fine and I cannot tell the difference between them.

My method looks like this:

```
    public ArrayList<Kiosk> getKiosks () {
    ArrayList<Kiosk> kioskArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();

    String[] columns = {Tags.TAG_LOCAL_ID, Tags.TAG_ID_SERVER, Tags.TAG_NAME,
                        Tags.TAG_PHONE_NUMBER, Tags.TAG_CONTACT_NAME, Tags.TAG_SCHOOL_ID};
    Cursor c = db.query(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_KIOSK, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    Log.i("tagg", "Size of the cursor is: " + c.getCount());

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        Kiosk kiosk = new Kiosk();
        kiosk.setLOCAL_ID(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Tags.TAG_LOCAL_ID)));
        kiosk.setIdServer(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Tags.TAG_ID_SERVER)));
        kiosk.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Tags.TAG_NAME)));
        kiosk.setPhoneNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Tags.TAG_PHONE_NUMBER)));
        kiosk.setContactName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Tags.TAG_CONTACT_NAME)));
        kiosk.setSchoolId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Tags.TAG_SCHOOL_ID)));
        c.moveToNext();
        kioskArrayList.add(kiosk);
        Log.w("taggg", "Added this to the kiosk Array: " + kiosk.getName() +
                "Local ID: " + kiosk.getLOCAL_ID());

    }
    Log.w("tagg", "getKioskhere, size of the array I sent is: " + kioskArrayList.size());

    c.close();
    db.close();
    return kioskArrayList;
}
```

My log gives clearly says the cursor's size is 2 but the ArrayList is 1:

```
     03-11 14:18:37.334: W/(18369): School id of the client is: 1
     03-11 14:18:37.336: I/(18369): Size of the cursor is: 2
     03-11 14:18:37.336: W/(18369): Added this to the kiosk Array: PitaKioskLocal ID: 2
     03-11 14:18:37.336: W/(18369): getKioskhere, size of the array I sent is: 1
```

Any advice? thanks in advance

Comment: You call `moveToFirst()` and then `moveToNext()` on the cursor before doing any processing.  So you're starting with the second record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first move to the first element:

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

Then you move to the second one, before you even processed the first one:

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {
```

Finally, you call

```
c.moveToNext();
```

within your while loop, which leads to ignoring every second entry.

Solution: remove the call within the loop, and process the first element before moving on to the second one. The easiest method would be to change `while(){}` to `do{} while()`.

Comment: For some reason I thought that I call the moveToNext() only for its boolean value, I don't know why I thought it won't actually move the cursor... Thanks a million !

Answer (score 0):

Set the sort order for the query. You also do a moveToNext() prior to any work.

```
Cursor c = db.query(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_KIOSK, columns, null, null, null, null, Tags.TAG_LOCAL_ID + " desc");

// stuff
do {

    // Iterate over cursor

} while (c.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling `moveToNext()` too many times.

You start at the first row with your call `moveToFirst()`. Then, as you enter your `while` loop, `moveToNext()` is called again. Thus, as you enter your loop you are already sitting on the second row. Then, inside the loop, you call `moveToNext()` and add your `kiosk` too the `kioskArrayList`.

When you hit the top of the `while` loop the second time, you are sitting at an index of 2, so `c.moveToNext()` evaluates to `false`, so you only add to the list once.